# Can a hyperbolic surface be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb R^4$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Can a complete hyperbolic surface be isometrically embedded into flat $\mathbb R^4$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is known that the hyperbolic plane can be isometrically immersed in $E^5$ (and isometrically embedded in $E^6$). Existence of an isometric immersion into $E^4$ is an open problem. Thus, the answer to your question is "unknown".

Comment: Thanks you studiosus.  Can you tell me where to find some information about this open problem?  And about the embedding into 6-space?

Comment: @HyperbolicAsker:  http://davidbrander.org/penn.pdf as well as "Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces",  By Qing Han, Jia-Xing Hong